# SQL query to Java String

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a simple question but I can't find a correct way to do it. When we use a query from SQL via Java we usually print the results in a JTable, my doubt it's ¿Is there a way to get that query into a Java String?

Example: I do a query
`statement.executeQuery("SELECT Tiempo_elaboracion FROM catalogo_arreglos WHERE Id_arreglo='"+id_arre+"'");`

The result is 00:07:00 ¿How can I save that result into a Java String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is actually a [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), which contains all matching rows (perhaps just one) and all selected columns (perhaps just one).

Some sequence such as

```
 if (!rs.first()) { ... error no first row ... }
 String str = rs.getString("Tiempo_elaboracion");
```

should do it.  But don't take this as gospel, I just peeked at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(java.lang.String)).  Use it as a starting point.

Answer (score -2):

I found an extra solution to complement, I post for all the people who needs help in the future.

```
ResultSet myRS;
PreparedStatement myQuery
//Under this line "con" is the name of my connection//
myQuery = con.prepareStatement(SELECT value FROM table WHERE condition)
myRS = myQuery.executeQuery();
//The purpose is the save the value of the query into the String called "time"
if(myRS.next()){
String time = myRS.getString(1);
//The next line only print the String "time" for corroborate the procces//
System.out.println(""+time);
}
```